# How can I use SIrange for this math?

Tags: siunitx

How can I use SIrange for this math?
I tried `$\alpha=S_1 \text{--} S_5$` but wondered if SIrange is better.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\begin{document}
$\alpha=\SIrange{S_1}{S_5}{}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about using interval-type notation, i.e., `$\alpha\in[S_1,S_5]$`?

Comment: @Mico but it's a range. Like S1, S2, S3, S4, S5.

Comment: The word "range" and the macro names `\numrange` and `\SIrange` usually imply that the number could be *anywhere* between the lower and upper bounds of the associated interval. If that's not the case, i.e., if the possible values of `\alpha` are discrete, you may want to write `$\alpha\in\{S_1,S_2,\dots,S_5\}$` to indicate this fact.

Comment: @Mico What if I have a list like `alpha = {S1-S5, S8, S10}`?

Comment: Moreover, `siunitx` is fundamentally for typesetting quantities, i.e., *numbers* with units, not mathematical symbols or formulas.

Comment: How would you write it, for example I have a list like `alpha = {S1-S20, S23, S30}`?

Comment: Are *any* numbers between `S_1` and `S_{20}` permissible values for `\alpha`, and are `S_{23}` and  `S_{30}` discrete values that aren't in the interval `[S_1,S_{20}]`?

Comment: If not, I would write `\alpha\in\{S_1,\dots,S_{20},S_{23},S_{30}\}`. The typographic ellipsis (`\dots`) is usually understood to subsum *all* possible values of `S_i` between `S_1` and `S_{20}`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with it then. S1 to S20 are consecutive from 1 to 20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This answer benefits from the fact that comments provided by the OP indicate that the numbers `S_1`, `S_2` etc are discrete and that `\alpha` has to be one of these discrete numbers.)

The word "range", when applied to numbers, generally implies that *any* value within the interval defined by the smallest and largest number in the range is possible. Since the OP's comments indicate that only discrete values are possible candidate values for `\alpha`, it doesn't look like it's appropriate to talk about a *range* of numbers. Intead, I'd write

```
\alpha \in \{S_1,\dots,S_5, S_8, S_{10}\}
```

and

```
\alpha \in \{S_1,\dots,S_{20}, S_{23}, S_{30}\}
```

respectively; please note the use of `\in` instead of `=`. The typographic ellipse generated by `\dots` indicates that *any* value of `S_i` from `S_1` to `S_5` (or, in the case of the second example, `S_{20}`) is a permissible value of `\alpha`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\alpha \in \{ S_1,\dots,S_5, S_8, S_{10} \}$

$\alpha \in \{ S_1,\dots,S_{20}, S_{23}, S_{30} \}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd not use `\SIrange` for this, as it's overkill.

If you want to devise your own nonstandard notation, please explain it before usage. And how can you define it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\rangedash}{{\operatorname{--}}}

\begin{document}

$\alpha\in\{S_{1} \rangedash S_{20},S_{23},S_{30}\}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Three facts are exploited here:

1. `{\operatorname{...}}` makes an ordinary symbol;
2. `\operatorname` is used so the hyphen in it is not interpreted as a minus sign;
3. `\operatorname` uses the standard text font for the characters in its argument, so the ligature `--` is correctly interpreted.

Comment: This is much better than my `\text{--}` as the font for the dash seem to match.